# Java adding extra passed variables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, irc, bots

First of all, I should probably mention that I'm pretty new to Java.

I'm using PircBot and JDBC to make an irc bot that returns some MySQL values. The problem I'm having is that I want to make prepared statements to protect from SQL injection. However, because I can't add extra variables into my method, I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my code as of now: http://pastebin.com/K8zCKt9f

Basically, I want to use prepared SQL statements, but I can't pass Connection conn into the onMessage method without it messing up (onMessage does not trigger on IRC). This means that I'd have to create a new connection every time there's an if statement, as opposed to how it works right now with the MySQL method.

I'm sure there's an easier/cleaner way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you're getting a connection every time the mysql method is invoked. I don't understand from your code why it would trigger in one method instead of another.Is what you're trying to avoid copies of the connection code? 

To avoid recreating a connection on every invocation use a connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a member variable to store the connection, and construct the connection when the Ross-object is constructed:

```
public class Ross extends PircBot {

    private Connection conn;


    public Ross() {

            this.setName("RICK_ROSS");
            this.setVersion("v1.0");
            this.setLogin("not_a_bot");
            if (!main.password.equals("")) this.sendMessage(main.loginbot, "auth "+main.username+" "+main.password);

            //Set up MySQL-connection
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"","");
    }
    ...The rest...
```

Now you can use the member variable *conn* in other methods of the class.

Comment: What's the second parameter that I should add for calling the MySQL method then? I've added that code so that it gets the connection information, but now I need two variables passed into MySQL because of this: public String MySQL (String statement, Connection conn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException { What should I add in String result = MySQL(statement);? I've tried String result = MySQL(statement, null); but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: ' String result = MySQL(statement, conn); ' The conn-variable is a member variable of the class and available in all your member-methods and stores the connection instantiated in the constructor. You probably should read more about object-oriented programming...

Comment: Right, but I can't actually add conn because it's not passed into the method head onMessage. When I pass it in, the onMessage method does not seem to work (it doesn't reply to any messages on IRC).

Comment: The signature (return type and passed in parameters) of the onMessage-method is dictated by the class PircBot your class extends. You cannot change the return type or the parameters. But again, conn is a member-variable, you can use it in any (non-static) method inside the Ross-class, because it is a member of the class, no need to pass it in the parameters of the method, you just write ' String result = MySQL(statement, conn); ' and the code reads the variable which was stored in  ' private Connection conn;
' during the call to the constructor ' public Ross() '.

Comment: Thanks for the help and in depth explanation. I really appreciate your help. It turns out I just misplaced the location of the private Connection conn;

Comment: No problem! Object-oriented programming can seem a bit weird until you get into it, I'd suggest you read through some tutorials. Here's one that explains the basics: http://www.iismarconi.net/inside/materiale/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/  , you can find loads more with some googling.